# Why does this recursive factorial lead to infinite recursion?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, racket

In one of my classes we are learning about functional programming, and I was told that this Racket code:

```
(define (my-if-bad x y z)
    (if x y z))

(define (factorial-bad n)
    (my-if-bad (= n 0) 1 (* n (factorial-bad (- n 1)))))
```

Will lead to infinite recursion. I understand this has to do with the fact that `if` statements are lazily evaluated, but I'm not sure exactly what that means for this scenario. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

First we have to clarify a few things,

Going forward I assume you are running in `#lang racket`

To be a little bit more accurate in terms of terminology, `if` statements are `short-circuiting`. What that means is for an expression `(if b x y)` the nested expression `y` will **NOT** evaluate if `b` is `true`. Similarly `x` will not evaluate if `b` is false.

However, that is not what is going on here (replace `my-if-bad` with regular `if` and everything works. Actually quite the opposite. What is happening is **function arguments in Racket are evaluated once, eagerly at function application**.

- So essentially in order to call `my-bad-if`:
- you first need to evaluate `(factorial-bad (- n 1))` but
- In order to evaluate `(factorial-bad (- n 1))` you need to call `my-bad-if`
- In order to call `my-bad-if` you need to evaluate `(factorial-bad (- n 1))`

and so on.

So the terminating case never stops the evaluation.

The best way to understand this is the following code

```
(define y 5)

(define a (begin
            (set! y (+ y 1))
            y))

(define (add x) (+ x  x))
```

There are two possibilities here, when calling `add` with `a`:

1. Either this expands to

```
 (+ (begin (set! y (+ y 1)) y) (begin (set! y (+ y 1)) y))
```

2. Or it expands to something like the following

```
(let [x (begin (set! y (+ y 1)) y)]
    (+ x x)
```

If it was the former, then

1. The first `x` would set `y= 5 + 1 = 6`
2. And then the second `x` evaluates `y = 6 + 1 = 7`
3. We would get `13`

Which is *NOT* the case.

So in your case by the time the `if` statement inside `my-if-bad` is hit, the values are already evaluated and the `if`'s short circuiting ability is meaningless

If you use the `stepper` in `DrRacket` you can see how the evaluation unfolds, and the `n` going `-1, -2, -3...`

Hope this helps